# index 1 out of string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Here is what am trying to do..

There is an array of strings in my rails app here `model_name_arr` and i want to make a regular expression out of it but at some specific position.
Which is displayed in line `#3` and `#4`
I am geting the desired output for `line #3` but executing the `line #4` in console gives the error

```
b = e.match(/\d[a-z]/i).to_s
SyntaxError Exception: 
/app/controllers/xyz_controller.rb:266: syntax error, unexpected '='
= e.match(/\d[a-z]/i)
 ^
*** Unknown class = e.match(/\d[a-z]/i)
```

which results in the error at line #6 with **index 1 out of string**
Help required.. am stuck

```
model_name_arr.each do |f|
    e = f
    a = e.match(/[a-z]\d/i).to_s     #here e = "yz450f" #> "z4"
    b = e.match(/\d[a-z]/i).to_s     #here e = "yz450f" #> "0f"
    a1= a.insert(1, '\\s?')
    b1= b.insert(1, '\\s?')    
    e.gsub!(/#{a}/,a1)
    e.gsub!(/#{b}/,b1)
    e_reg = Regexp.new(e)
    if @link.match(e_reg)
        @model_name = f
    end
end
```

Thanks already :)

Comment: it seems you have inserted non-breakable space here: `b = e.match(/\d[a-z]/i).to_s` , please check it.

Comment: and please inster code WITH RIGHT SYNTAX AS IT IS!

Comment: will surely keep in mind as am new
well finding the value in console of **b** returns the following statement..
`Created breakpoint 3 at ../app/controllers/xyz_controller.rb:266`

Comment: please provide real task, i.e. what is value of `f`, and what do you want to get, in this case `e_reg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get the syntax error you experience when using the code above - check that the text doesn't have invisible non-ascii characters...

The error `index 1 out of string` happens when you try to call `insert(1, 'something')` on a string length shorter than 1 (i.e. an empty string).

In your code this will happen if there is no match in one of the `e.match(/something/i).to_s`. If you don't expect that to happen, you might want to check whether the strings you pass in the array really contain what you think they contain.

I think this might be an option, since you mutate them (change their content) in the code above, probably inadvertently - `e.gsub!` changes the string in `e`. Although you think you are changing a temporary variable by assigning `f` to `e` in this line:

```
e = f
```

you are actually still changing the string inside the array, because you copied the *reference* to it, rather than the *value*.

To properly copy the value you need to change the above line to:

```
e = f.dup
```

Although a better way might be to refrain from using `gsub!` but rather use `gsub`, something like this:

```
e_reg = Regexp.new(f.gsub(/#{a}/,a1).gsub(/#{b}/,b1))
```

Comment: Well it helped me a lot for clearing out many other things but I had to convert all **local variables** to **instance variables** and the last regex you wrote , I had to edit it as `e_reg = Regexp.new(e.gsub(/#{a}/,a1).gsub(/#{b}/,b1))` worked!!
Thanks bro..